# Different pages on same domain show different cookies (by target domain)

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, session-cookies, openid-connect

I have a Single Sign On implementation that adds cookies to a website when people login. I see the cookie in the chrome Inspector when looking at one page, but not in another page on the same domain.

- The cookie path is set to "/", so should be available on all files
- The target domain for the disappearing cookie is another domain

When I go to one page on the site, I see many cookies (including with various target domains).

When I go to other pages on the same domain, I see fewer cookies (*all seem to be with the local domain as target*)

Using Apache, SSL, Ubuntu, it's a sub-domain, it's a session cookie, using exact  same https and www in url, all standard stuff.

**How come different pages on same domain can show different cookies, (in chrome Inspector)?**

Obviously the clue here is the cookie target domain, but why is that an issue?

Comment: In case it makes a difference, the cookie was generated by this OpenID library: https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party cookies are only shown, if there’s any requests to those domains happening in the context of the current page.

Let’s say your domain is `A`, and you have a cookie set for domain `B` in your browser.

Your page `1` embeds *something* from domain `B` - could be an image, a script file, … - anything that causes an actual HTTP request to domain `B` to be made. Then you will see the cookie for domain `B` listed in dev tools.

Your page `2` however does not embed any such resources from domain `B`. No cookies from `B` are actually “involved” now in what happens on this page `2` - so no need or reason for dev tools to show them now either, while you are on page `2`.

Comment: Yes, I tried and this is how it works! So even though the cookies exist globally on the site, the tool won't show it unless there is a reference to the domain on a page. Very confusing for debugging, as it looked as if the cookie was never received!